# OnCollisionEnter2D fails to send information

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

I am testing OnCollisonEnter2D and it doesn't seem to want to work for me.
I have box collider 2d and rigidbody2d's on both of my game objects and again, it fails to send a message to the console.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CollisionAndResetSystem : MonoBehaviour {
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Cube")
        print ("hit");

}
}
```

I took this strait from the Scripting API and it doesn't want to work.

Comment: I just straight up spelled collision wrong...

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the script. Problem must be in your "boxcollider2d" component. Please check the size of "boxcollider2d", change it to something like 100 in both x and y and in both the gameobjects also. Please check in the scene view if you can see the "boxcollider2d" gizmo. You have to make "boxcollider2d" as big as your gameobjects, then only OnCollisionEnter2D will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need your objects to be affected by physics
then set `isKinematic = false` and `Gravity Scale = 0` and remember to attach your `OnCollisionEnter2D` script to your `gameObject`

Answer (score 0):

A Couple of things:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Cube")
        print ("hit");
}
```

1. Make sure you are comparing with a correct tag (keep the *case sensitivity* in mind).
2. Make sure the gameObject that is being compared has this tag linked. May be you defined the tag but there is no gameObject with this tag.
3. Check the size of your collider component, it should be enough big to receive touch event.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Most important is that check on which gameobject your script is attached,Cross check that your script are attached to your gameobject that you are trying get collision with. And Use Debug.log() too in place of Print(),Hope this help.